# Why does array cast Int32[] to UInt32[] work only after conversion through Object?

Tags: c#, casting

It's obvious that UInt32 can not accurately represent Int32 values, but what's the mechanism behind the following chain conversion allowing to perform cast?

```
        Int32[] a = { 1, 20, 0, 5, 7, 9};
        UInt32[] b = (UInt32[])(Object)a;
```

Comment: The result will be the same as individually casting each `int` to a `uint` -- i.e. negative values become large positive values